# JAVA always read the directory from where jar is executed

Tags: java, path, directory

I have a small java app that updates files in a set location.
the app reads from a UpdateFiles folder, moves the files in this folder to the appropriate folder. the app works. what i want to know is how should i set my path if i want the app to always try and look for the UpdateFiles folder in same location that the app is? for example if the app is executed from desktop i want it to look for the UpdateFiles folder in desktop, same for any other location. The app runs on windows and AIX/linux enviroments

thank you / kind regards

Comment: Please define what do you mean under "location of the app". Is it the folder with *.jar and root of *.class file(s)? Or is it current directory where the java is started from?

Comment: the location of the ".JAR" file. i understand what all the users mean, but the application will be used on multiple servers with different directory structures and permissions. i move the .jar app onto the server, execute it and then remove it again. so if i place jar in /usr/test/ i want the app to look for the UpdateFiles folder in the /usr/test/ folder. if i place the jar in /usr/test/test2/ i want it to look for the UpdateFiles folder in /usr/test/test2/ directory. this is as clear as i can explain it. i hope it makes sense

Comment: As far as I understand you always assume, that your application is placed within ONE jar file with the starting class. How do you start your application? Why just don't just use a starting parameter where you can explicitly specify working path? For example `java -jar myapp.jar -DmyWorkDir=/usr/test2`

Answer (score 2):

You can access the system property that contains the current working directory:

```
String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: Or you can use the default path.  The "user.home" might be a better place to store files.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the location of the jar file, but this is not the same as the current working directory (the directory you get if you don't specify a path)

However the location of the jar is rarely a good place to store files and you don't want to mix released programs with files as this make upgrading your software much more complex.

I suggest using the user's home directory `System.getProperties("user.home");` or a sub-directory This doesn't change if you upgrade you software is should always be writable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your app from the dir where UpdateFiles is located, if necessary you can create a bat file (for Windows) and run it from any location

`cd c:\path_to_UpdateFiles
java MyApp`

do something similar in Linux